# How can you tell which pane in Tmux is focused?

Tags: tmux

I'm starting to use tmux (I'm thinking of switching from screen), but I'm having a hard time telling which pane is focused when I split a window into multiple panes. Is there a config customization or something that can highlight the focused pane a little more explicitly?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Here are the relevant settings:

```
pane-active-border-style fg=colour,bg=colour
    Set the pane border colour for the currently active pane.
```

So, try adding something like this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g pane-active-border-style fg=blue
```

That will set a blue border around the active pane. The `pane-active-border-style bg=colour` option can be used for a more visible solution, as well.

Comment: I don't see this option on my man page, and it's not recognized by my version of tmux.

Comment: @dan Ah, you know, I had to install tmux 1.4 from source because Ubuntu repositories only had version 1.3. They're pretty different, and I really recommend doing the newer one. It's a bit more flexible.

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know. Annoyingly, tmux doesn't (?) seem to have a way to show you which version you're running.

Comment: @dan Haha, I noticed that too. Ironically, I think it's one of the features added in 1.4: `tmux -V`. If you're on Ubuntu or a debian-based system, you can check with `dpkg -l | grep tmux`.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, unfortunately if you just have a single split, all it does is color the divider and it doesn't change no matter which pane is active.

Comment: Note that this is fixed in more recent versions. It now colors only half the divider depending on which panel you are in.

Comment: Yes, if you have only one vertical split the top half of the border is `pane-active-border-bg` while the bottom is `pane-border-bg`.

Comment: Syntax has changed (ref: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1689). It would be `pane-active-border-style fg=blue` etc. It'd be great if you can edit your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 44):

As answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532773/change-background-color-of-active-or-inactive-pane-in-tmux/33553372#33553372) it is now possible in tmux 2.1 to set the colours of individual panes. Ones can use:

```
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'
```

in the `~/.tmux.conf` file to show a difference between the active/inactive panes.

**With Vim** If you find it does not work with Vim panes, it might be down to the colourscheme you are using. First, try another colourscheme such as `pablo`. For further details, see the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532773/change-background-color-of-active-or-inactive-pane-in-tmux/33553372#33553372).

Comment: @Solidak It might be the Vim colourscheme you are using - please see the other post for further details.

Comment: Weird that the options are "window-style" and "window-active-style" but it's referring to tmux panes, not tmux windows.

Answer (score 15):

Customize `status-left` and use the `#P` character pair, which is the pane number. You will probably want to include more than just the pane number in the status bar, but here is an example of the line you would add to your `~/.tmux.conf` for just the pane number:

```
set-option -g status-left '#P'
```

See the tmux man page for more character pairs: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html

Comment: Ah, just realized you're going for a highlight on the focused pane, more so than just a status indicator. Hopefully this is helpful for now. Sorry for misreading the question.

Answer (score 7):

One Solution that works for me is to add a display-pane at the end of the hotkey for a pane switch. This displays all the pane numbers, with the current pane in a different color. You can also use `<escape_key> + q` to display pane numbers.

I use `alt+h/j/k/l` to switch between panes, and I use the following binding.

```
bind -n M-j select-pane -D \; display-pane                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bind -n M-k select-pane -U \; display-pane                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bind -n M-h select-pane -L \; display-pane                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bind -n M-l select-pane -R \; display-pane
```

Answer (score 0):

For tmux 3 I was able to set the following in my .tmux.conf for a subtle border indicator:

```
set-option -g pane-active-border-style bg=yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

[ctrl+b, z] zooms in the focused pane, and [ctrl+b, z] zooms out. So you'll figure out which pane is focused. Just to share.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted the active pane's borders to be brighter than other panes,
so I went with this (works in tmux 1.8 w/CentOS 7):

## ~/.tmux.conf fragment

```
# rgb hex codes from https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg '#33FF33' # brighter green
set-option -g pane-border-fg '#006600' # darker green
```

The tmux man page says hex-RGB colors will be approximated, and I find the hex codes easier to understand than remembering "colour47" (out of colour0-255) is a kind of light green (as described in [How does the tmux color palette work?](https://superuser.com/questions/285381/how-does-the-tmux-color-palette-work)).

## tmux man-page excerpt:

```
message-bg colour
    Set status line message background colour, ...etc...
    or a hexadecimal RGB string such as ‘#ffffff’, which chooses the closest
    match from the default 256-colour set.
```