# Change background color of active or inactive pane in Tmux

Tags: tmux

Are there any options to control the background color of the active or inactive panes in Tmux?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It seems that [tmux-2.1](https://tmux.github.io/) (released 18 October 2015) now allows the colours of individual panes to be specified. From the [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES):

```
* 'select-pane' now understands '-P' to set window/pane background colours.
```

e.g. [from the manual] to change pane 1's foreground (text) to blue and background to red use:

```
select-pane -t:.1 -P 'fg=blue,bg=red'
```

#### To mimic iTerm colour scheme:

To answer the original question, I use the following lines in my `~/.tmux.conf` for setting the background/foreground colours to mimic the behaviour in [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/):

```
#set inactive/active window styles
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

# set the pane border colors 
set -g pane-border-style 'fg=colour235,bg=colour238' 
set -g pane-active-border-style 'fg=colour51,bg=colour236'
```

I hadn't seen the `window-style` and `window-active-style` commands before, but maybe they were available in previous tmux versions.

Also, these two lines are pretty useful for splitting panes easily:

```
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
```

**EDIT**: as [Jamie Schembri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484973/jamie-schembri) mentions in the comments, tmux version 2.1 (at least) will now be installed with:

```
brew install tmux
```

**EDIT (Oct 2017)**: brew now installs tmux 2.6, and the above still works.

**EDIT Vim panes**: If you find that the "inactive colouring" does not work with a Vim pane, it might be due to the colourscheme you are using. Try with the `pablo` scheme; i.e. in the Vim pane:

```
:colo pablo
```

To make it work with your own custom Vim colourscheme, make sure that the setting for `Normal` highlighting does not have `ctermbg` or `guibg` specified. As an example, the "inactive colouring" does not work with the `murphy` colourscheme, because in `murphy.vim` there is the line:

```
hi Normal    ctermbg=Black   ctermfg=lightgreen   guibg=Black   guifg=lightgreen
```

that sets `ctermbg` or `guibg` to `Black`. However, changing this line to:

```
hi Normal    ctermfg=lightgreen  guifg=lightgreen
```

will make the "inactive colouring" work.

**EDIT July 2019** [Augusto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2179883/augusto) provided a good suggestion for also changing the background colour for the line numbers. What I use in my vim colourscheme is the following (you need to find and edit the colourscheme file):

```
hi Normal    guifg=#e6e1de ctermfg=none gui=none
hi LineNr    guifg=#e6e1de ctermfg=none gui=none
```

Comment: `brew` now installs 2.1. Side-note: this works great with [vim-diminactive](https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive).

Comment: I'm just going to post all the available [x-term color](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) here to save people making second guesses (like I did) when choosing the color.

Comment: is it possible to change the tmux pane color when ssh'ing?

Comment: Updated x-term colour chart: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg

Comment: Hmm, using `select-pane ...` works to change the pane colors, but `window-style` and `window-active-style` don't seem to have any effect. Running `tmux 2.6` in `iTerm`. Any ideas?

Comment: Follow up: I moved it to the top of my `.tmux.conf` and now it works! (Took just too long that I can't edit comment; I think it's worth leaving for posterity though)

Comment: For those new to the target option (`-t`), the syntax is `-t:w.p` where `w` is a window number and `p` is the pane number (use `0` if the window is not split). Also, be sure to preface any hex color value with a `#`: `bg=#5f0000`.

Comment: If you want the background of the line-numbers to change as well (It looks weird if it doesn't) apply the LineNr settings the same you did to the Normal settings (make sure it doesn't specify `ctermbg` or `guibg`)

Comment: Thanks! This has been a great resource. My colorscheme (base16-solarized-light) sets both guifg and ctermfg. So, I tried clearing Normal using `:hi clear Normal` and set only guifg and ctermfg. However, that doesn't work. It works only if I update `:hi Normal` in the colorscheme file itself and omit guibg and ctermbg there. Is this normal?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I had to edit the colourscheme file itself (perhaps this was not clear above).

Comment: To make this work for a complex Vim color scheme (e.g. `gruvbox`), add `highlight Normal guibg=NONE` after setting the color scheme: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730359/597831

Answer (score 8):

There is no option to change the background color of a pane, but there is option to set the pane-border color (style)

```
 pane-active-border-style style
                     Set the pane border style for the currently active 
pane.  For how to specify style, see the message-command-style option. 
 Attributes are ignored.


 pane-border-style style
                     Set the pane border style for paneas aside from the 
active pane.  For how to specify style, see the message-command-style option. 
 Attributes are
                     ignored.
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming, I have pane-border-style set but was hoping for the whole pane color.

Answer (score 2):

On version 3.1, you can set hooks on pane focus in or out. You must set `focus-events` to 'on' first.

In a combination of [dean.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095511/dean)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553372/20724811) and [user21952-is-a-great-name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563359/user21952-is-a-great-name)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464590/20724811), the `pane-focus-out` hook fires on the pane that you are moving out of, and you set the background and foreground appropriately - I used a slightly dimmer color scheme. The `pane-focus-in` hook then fires on the pane that is getting focus, and I set the colors both to default.

I didn't bother setting a target on `select-pane` as it seems to work without it, but there is an option for `{last}` (or `{!}`) according to [the wiki](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Advanced-Use#command-targets).

```
set -g focus-events on
set-hook -g pane-focus-out 'select-pane -P bg=colour0,fg=colour10'
set-hook -g pane-focus-in 'select-pane -P bg=default,fg=default'
```

This appears to work in my terminal but does not affect colors of an open Vim session. It also fires when I scroll up, it seems the copy mode also unsets focus.

Answer (score 1):

I like this variation of [***dean***'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553372):

```
# Make sure your 16-color terminal theme uses slightly
# different colors for `background` vs `black` (AKA `color0`).
# "Nord" or "Tango dark" themes do this out of the box.
# Use `white` instead of `black` for light themes.

set -g window-active-style 'fg=terminal,bg=terminal'
set -g window-style 'fg=terminal,bg=black'

set focus-events on
set-hook -g client-focus-in "set window-active-style 'fg=terminal,bg=terminal'"
set-hook -g client-focus-out "set window-active-style 'fg=terminal,bg=black'"
```

The last three lines may require a recent version of tmux (I use tmux 3.3),
and mark *all* panes inactive when the terminal window is not focused. I am not sure if `set focus-events on` is necessary. The lack of `-g` *inside* the hook is important (the subtle bug that prevents is left as an exercise to a reader interested in tmux arcana).

You can, of course, use a different `window-style` (e.g. `brightblack`, or `fg=white,bg=black`).

### Older answer (a different approach)

Since tmux 3.3 (released Jun 1, 2022, so it may not have propagated to all distributions yet), there are new options to help disambiguate which pane is active (though these don't change the background color specifically):

```
# I find this together with default coloring of the active pane border sufficient
set -g pane-border-lines heavy

# More explicit options that I find a bit excessive
set -g pane-border-lines number
set -g pane-border-indicators both # Displays arrows pointing to the current pane.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
# highlight focused pane (tmux >= 2.1), possible values are:
#   - true
#   - false (default)
tmux_conf_theme_highlight_focused_pane=true

# focused pane colours:
#tmux_conf_theme_focused_pane_fg='default'
tmux_conf_theme_focused_pane_bg='#191919'
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you edited it and included an explanation of why you think this answers the question.