# How do I change the color for directories with ls using tmux?

Tags: ssh, tmux, ls

I am using a bash function to change the foreground and background color of tmux pane if I am in a dev or prod remote server.

#### .bash_profile

```sh
function sshTmuxColor() {
    if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
        case "$1" in
        prod_*)
            tmux selectp -P 'fg=white,bg=colour52' #colour124=darker-red
        ;;
        dev_*)
            tmux selectp -P 'fg=white,bg=colour22' # color28=darker-green
        ;;
        esac
    fi
    ssh "$@"
    tmux selectp -P default
}
alias ssh=sshTmuxColor
```

Is it possible to change the color of directories on the remote server when I use `ls`? Or am I better of optimizing my colors for whatever the color of remote directories are? (Changing them is not really an option). This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186998/change-background-color-of-tmux-pane-depending-on-remote-hostname/57187399#57187399).

Comment: Consult the man page of the `ls` in question; it will describe how to configure the colors `ls` uses for its own output.

Comment: chepner... did you see the bit on how modifying the ls colors directly via the `.bashrc` is not really an option?

Comment: Who said anything about modifying `.bashrc`?

Comment: RTFM is not super helpful. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: At the very least, you have to know *which* `ls` you are using. For example, BSD `ls` and GNU `ls` use different environment variables to configure what colors `ls` should use. But in either case, you can set environment variables independently of `.bashrc`.

Comment: You asked if it is possible to change the color of directories on the remote server: yes, it is.

Comment: *using tmux....

Comment: `tmux` is irrelevant. `ls` is responsible for outputting the color codes for different file types.

Comment: I asked "How do I change the color for directories with ls using tmux?". I did not ask, "if it is possible to change the color of directories on the remote server" as you stated.

Comment: Yes: you *don't* change the color for directories with `ls` using `tmux`. `ls` outputs color codes; it's the terminal's (which, to some extent means `tmux`) responsibility for interpreting those codes as changes to the current foreground and/or background colors, but `tmux` itself has no concept of those color changes being associated with directories or any other file type. The most `tmux` (or your terminal in general) could do is change all requests for color #1 from black to red. It is *entirely* up to `ls` to decide how to handle directory names.