# How to style active pane border in Tmux?

Tags: tmux, archlinux

The problem is I somehow styled the active border so that it's bright orange and about 5px thick on all sides.  I don't remember what command caused this.

I have no problem styling non-active borders using the line `set -g pane-border-style fg=brightblack`.  But using the same format to style the active border with `set -g pane-active-border-style fg=white` yields no effect.

Maybe I'm trying to style the wrong thing?  Is there some other pane property that overlaps the active pane?

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889724/how-can-you-easily-tell-which-pane-in-tmux-is-focused

Comment: I found that question and tried the solution but it didn't work.  I think the information is outdated for newer versions of Tmux.

Answer (score 3):

It was actually the pane-active-border-bg property, but I had to restart tmux to apply the changes in this instance.

Comment: As an alternative to restarting, you can make your changes effective using `<prefix>` + `: source ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: Just to clarify on the response, if I may, removing pane-active-border-bg property will make the border 1px thin